# Is there a system Task that can take a photo in the WinRT API?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, webcam, image-capture

I have used the photo chooser task in my C# Window Store apps (WinRT) before.  On Windows Phone there is a complementary task that you can launch that lets the user take a photo, and it returns a reference to the image data for your consumption.  I can't seem to find the same thing in the Windows Store app API.  I know about the capture media API and the camera capture API in WinRT, but it's obviously easier if there's a full blown task I can launch to handle the whole picture taking operation, rather than coding up something by myself.  Is there such a facility in the Windows Store Apps API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 8.1 (not Phone) the [Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.aspx) class is really easy to use--just a couple lines of code, and it has built-in features like camera selection, pixel density, and cropping:

```
using Windows.Media.Capture; 
using Windows.Storage; 

CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI(); 
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

The file variable will have the captured image. Refer to the [Camera Capture UI sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac) for more details and usage.

Do note that if you're targeting a universal Windows 8.1 app, this API isn't available on that version of Windows Phone and you'll need to write your own capture routine as Aurelien demonstrates.

Answer (score 1):

Coding something by yourself to so this task is not that hard.

I answered to a similar question already you could use the answer :

[Windows (Phone) 8.1 Camera Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137683/windows-phone-8-1-camera-use/26153213#26153213)

I rewrite my answer down there, it contains the code to look for webcams on the device, initialize the one you choose, and take picture from it and save it where you want.

The code was intended for windows phone, for desktop or tablet apps the only thing i would change is webcam selection as the user could be using an external webcam maybe the pc doesn't have built-in ones.

Here is the code:

First the initialization part

```
// First need to find all webcams
DeviceInformationCollection webcamList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.All)
```

*(in the following lines I get the front and back webcam, but for non phone apps
you better either choose index 0 of the webcamList for example)*

```
// Then I do a query to find the front webcam
DeviceInformation frontWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
 where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null 
 && webcam.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front
 select webcam).FirstOrDefault();

// Same for the back webcam
DeviceInformation backWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
 where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null 
 && webcam.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back
 select webcam).FirstOrDefault();

// Then you need to initialize your MediaCapture
newCapture  = new MediaCapture();
await newCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
    {
        // Choose the webcam you want
        VideoDeviceId = backWebcam.Id,
        AudioDeviceId = "",
        StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
        PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
    });

// Set the source of the CaptureElement to your MediaCapture
// (In my XAML I called the CaptureElement *Capture*)
Capture.Source = newCapture;

// Start the preview
await newCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Secondly take the picture

```
//Set the path of the picture you are going to take
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var picPath = "\\Pictures\\newPic.jpg";

StorageFile captureFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(picPath, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

//Capture your picture into the given storage file
await newCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, captureFile);
```

Done! the picture is saved at the given path in your Application storage folder.